# Unexpected output when querying joint tables in sequelize js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to query records from two tables which have a one to many relationship using the following code using sequelize.
In this case one author can have many books while a book can be authored by only one author.

```
const BookList = await Book.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Author,
      attributes: ['name'],
    },
  ],
  raw: true,
});
```

**Books Model**

```
const Books = sequelize.define(
  'books',
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    author_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'authors',
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    tableName: 'books',
  },
);
```

**Authors Model**

```
const Authors = sequelize.define(
  'authors',
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    tableName: 'authors',
  },
);
```

The expected outcome would be something as follows.

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "book1",
    author_id: 1,
    author: {
      name: "tom",
    }
  },
  .....
]
```

However the outcome i am getting is as follows.

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "book1",
    author_id: 1,
    "author.name": "tom"
  },
  .....
]
```

My question would by why am i getting "author.name" instead of an author object as shown in many of the examples on the sequelize docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when you use `raw: true` you will receive the brut data  without any format and it's not bind to any model definition.

If you want sequelize to format the different (using dottie.js under the hood) objects you can use the property `nest: true`

```
const BookList = await Book.findAll({
  include: [
      {
        model: Author,
        attributes: ['name'],
      },
  ],
  raw: true,
  nest: true
});
```

Here the link to the documentation: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html